# Using the Lync 2013 SDK in a multithreaded application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, lync

I want to use the Lync 2013 SDK in a WPF application to query contact availability, although I’m seeing some strange behaviour. I suspect this is because of the way I am calling it from many threads at a time, although not sure of the best approach to resolve this.

I have a custom UserControl for displaying contact information for people within our company. I load a collection of these controls into a single form based on a search query. Each contact control will load detailed information about the contact on creation, using the ThreadPool to apply some throttling. All information up until this point is coming from AD, which has been working well.

Now I want to show the contact availability status of each contact. I have put together this code, which has been modified from another post.

```
    private LyncClient _lyncClient;
    private ContactSubscription _contactSubscription;

    private void GetContactAvailability(string sip)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sip))
        {
            _lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();

            if (_lyncClient.State == ClientState.SignedIn)
            {
                _lyncClient.ContactManager.BeginSearch(
                    sip,
                    SearchProviders.Default,
                    SearchFields.EmailAddresses,
                    SearchOptions.ContactsOnly,
                    1,
                    BeginSearchCallback,
                    new object[] {_lyncClient.ContactManager, sip});
            }
        }
    }

    private void BeginSearchCallback(IAsyncResult r)
    {
        var asyncState = (object[]) r.AsyncState;
        var cm = (ContactManager) asyncState[0];
        var results = cm.EndSearch(r);

        if (results.AllResults.Count > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(results.Contacts.Count);
            Microsoft.Lync.Model.Contact contact = results.Contacts[0];
            UpdateLyncStatus(contact);
            _contactSubscription = cm.CreateSubscription();
            _contactSubscription.AddContact(contact);
            contact.ContactInformationChanged += contact_ContactInformationChanged;
            ContactInformationType[] contactInformationTypes = {ContactInformationType.Availability};
            _contactSubscription.Subscribe(ContactSubscriptionRefreshRate.High, contactInformationTypes);
        }
    }

    private void contact_ContactInformationChanged(object sender, ContactInformationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var contact = (Microsoft.Lync.Model.Contact) sender;
        UpdateLyncStatus(contact);
    }

    private void UpdateLyncStatus(Microsoft.Lync.Model.Contact contact)
    {
        if ((_lyncClient != null) && (_lyncClient.State == ClientState.SignedIn))
        {
            UpdateLyncStatus((ContactAvailability) contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability));
        }
    }
```

If my search form returns only a single result, then this code seems to work every time to successfully return the availability status for a single contact control. If I do a more generic search, such as “John” (which returns 50+ results), only a few (if any) of the contacts show the availability status. The code doesn’t generate any exceptions, it just doesn’t work.

If I repeat the search for “John” again, then all of the contacts will show an availability status. I suspect these statuses are cached from the previous Lync search, which is great, but how do I get them to show in the first search?

Is there a better way to use the Lync SDK in a multithreaded application?